# pygame error: Tuple has no attribute get_size()

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried everything I can think of to get this background to work, this is the closest I have gotten as it breaks no other bits of my code. I am unsure why get_size() doesn't work.

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode = ((display_width, display_height))
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
pygame.display.set_caption("Catastrophee")
background = pygame.Surface(gameDisplay.get_size())
background = background.convert()
```

This is only a snippet of the code. I have all variables properly defined.

Please help,
thanks, Cam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this helps?

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height)) #removed =
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
pygame.display.set_caption("Catastrophee")
background = pygame.Surface(gameDisplay.get_size())
background = background.convert()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
```

Just delete second = from that line

Answer (score 1):

You should :

```
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])
```

Not

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode = ((display_width, display_height))
```